# iPhone: Core Plot, pie charts

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I have a pie chart that I build using Core Plot. Also I used

> -(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
>   recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index

to add labels to every slice.

What I want to do is to add line from text to slice, and make it clickable, because slice can be too small, and that will be vary hard for user to click on that slice. Have any body any idea ? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't supported in Core Plot right now. You can request a new feature on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).